# Blank window in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am getting a blank page when running the below Python program. I am running this code on Python 3.3.

```
from tkinter import *

class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.master = master

        self.init_window()

    def init_window(self):
        self.master.title("GUI")
        self.pack(fill = BOTH,expand = 1)
        #quitbutton = Button(self, text = "Quit", command= self.client_exit)
        #quitbutton.place(x=0,y=0)
        menu = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu = menu)

        file = Menu(menu)
        file.add_command(label = 'Exit', command = self.client_exit())
        menu.add_cascade(label='File', menu = file)

        edit = Menu(menu)
        edit.add_command(label = 'Undo')
        edit.add_cascade(label = 'Edit', menu = edit)

    def client_exit(self):
        exit()

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")
app = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: it gives error message bacause it exits program - `command=` needs function name - it means without `()` - correctly `command=self.client_exit` BTW: and use `root.destroy()` instead of `exit()` - it will close window.

Comment: If an answer solves your issue, please accept an answer and close the question.

Answer (score 1):

You put `()` to a function name `self.client_exit()`, for the `command` do it without `()`, as shown in the `quitbutton`

```
file = Menu(menu)
file.add_command(label = 'Exit', command = self.client_exit)
menu.add_cascade(label='File', menu = file)
```

Also don't use python keywords like `file` for variable names